# Display integer in msgbox throw conversion error

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I work throu an EF tutorial. Now there is a Listing:

```
Using context As New northwindEntities
            Dim query = From prod In context.Products
                        Where prod.UnitPrice = context.Products.Max(Function(x) x.UnitPrice)
                        Select prod.ProductName, prod.UnitPrice
            For Each item In query

                'works fine
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.ProductName, item.UnitPrice)
                'Not working error see below:
                MsgBox(item.ProductName, " ", item.UnitPrice.ToString)

            Next
        End Using
```

I get the Error: `Conversion from string to type 'Integer' is not valid.` Doesent matter if  I write `item.UnitPrice.ToString` or `item.UnitPrice`, error is still the same. But I just have no idea why? Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the [`MsgBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/139z2azd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function wrong.

Look what parameters it accepts:

```
Public Function MsgBox( _
   ByVal Prompt As Object, _
   Optional ByVal Buttons As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly, _
   Optional ByVal Title As Object = Nothing _
) As MsgBoxResult
```

When you call `MsgBox(item.ProductName, " ", item.UnitPrice.ToString)` you pass `" "` for the `Buttons` parameter, which should be of type `MsgBoxStyle` (or at least the underlying type: `Integer`, which VB.Net converts to `MsgBoxStyle` implicitly if you use `Option Strict Off`).

---

You're probably looking for something like:

```
MsgBox(String.Format("{0} {1}", item.ProductName, item.UnitPrice))
```

or

```
MsgBox(item.ProductName, MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly, item.UnitPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
second parameter of the MsgBox function takes an Enum (pretty much an integer) not a string.